# How to assign an id to a button that already has a Class attached to it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to assign an id to a button that already has a Class. I only can assign a new class with that code:

```
<script>
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var buttonFancy = $('.header-content .et_pb_more_button.et_pb_button_one');
        buttonFancy.each(function(){
            $(this).addClass('treeee');
        })
    });
})(jQuery)
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow! Please look over https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Since StackOverflow isn't a coding service It's required that you attempt to solve your problem before posting.

Comment: You can give an id to an element with `element.id = 'value'` or if it is a jQuery object you can do `variable.prop('id', 'value')`.  However keep in mind that ids are expected to be unique, so if multiple elements have that class, you don't want to give them all the same id.

Comment: `.attr('id', 'whatever-you-need-here')` I would ask why you feel the need to do this, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can change any attribute using `attr` (see https://api.jquery.com/attr/) `$(this).attr('id', 'myID' + index);` changes the id to "myID-" with the index of the current button.

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function(index) {
    var buttonFancy = $('.header-content .et_pb_more_button.et_pb_button_one');
    buttonFancy.each(index => {
      $(this).addClass('treeee');
      $(this).attr('id', 'button-' + index);
    })
  });
})(jQuery)
```

Comment: jQuery doesn't need to using loop for it methods. It apply methods for all selectors.

Comment: @Mohammad at that case you cannot add unique `id` dynamically to each element

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal of course you can: http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function

Comment: So do I. You can use the `index` argument exactly as yours and this answer does without the need to loop

Comment: @Taplar are you sure that doesn't loop behind the scenes?

Comment: Of course it loops behind the scenes.  But what Mohammad said was you do not have to explicitly do the loop yourself

Comment: @Taplar it would make sense if it would really help in minimizing the complexity. Both have same complexity.

Comment: It's less typing for the programmer.  Edit: also, as the logic already exists in the library, allowing jQuery to use the implict loop that it does is also reusing logic.  So in that sense, there is also a D.R.Y argument to be made.

Comment: @Taplar less ugly too.